# 405 POST Method Not Allowed in Visual Studio 2013/Local Host IIS 8.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with IIS 8.0 for development (local host) and am attempting to upload a file via jQuery Ajax, but it keeps throwing a 405 error stating that POST methods aren't allowed. I have tried adding multiple aspects to the Web.config, but none work. Here is my basic upload code (uploading an image converted from a Canvas) to a directory named myfiles:

```
        function imageMe() {
        var canvasImage = document.getElementById("c");
        var img = canvasImage.toDataURL("image/png");
        var filename = 'Test.png';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'myfiles/',
            type: "POST",
            data: img, 
            processData: false,
            headers: {
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Upload complete!");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This is question is, there is no way to determine why (Server code is missing).

Comment: I didn't realize server side code was needed. Does IIS support POST of files naturally

Comment: Yes since at least version 3.0 that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks @ErikPhilips. Any clues why it is not allowing a POST?

Comment: No because you haven't included all the required code, please read my first comment.

Comment: Appreciate the guidance. Are you looking for client side code, or the web.config as it stands?

Comment: *Server Side Code*.  You can't just *upload a file* to a server, there has to be some server code that accepts the file.

Comment: That explains it. I was under the assumption that since IIS supports a GET method, I could upload to it. I don't have any server side code in that case, and would need to develop an endpoint to support the POST. I really missed the obvious on this one!